# Django SuspisciousFileOperation

Tags: django, webfaction, saleor

I'm trying to install saleor using wsgi on webfaction. When I try to reach my page I receive a 500 error, and the logs show:

```
 SuspiciousFileOperation at /en/
 The joined path (/images/placeholder255x255.png) is located outside of the base path component (/home/<user>/lib/python3.6/versatileimagefield/static)
```

My settings are:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = 'https://img.website.com/saleor/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
 ('assets', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'saleor', 'static', 'assets')),
 ('favicons', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'saleor', 'static', 'favicons')),
 ('images', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'saleor', 'static', 'images')),
 ('dashboard', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'saleor', 'static', 'dashboard'))]
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Now this is of course the wrong base path component, but how can I fix that?

Comment: Where is the image's path defined? It looks like the path join would work if you could just get rid of that leading forward slash.

Comment: What are your `STATIC_*` and `MEDIA_*` settings?

Comment: Added the settings :)